# URL Masking In Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

Please I don't know how to go about this. I searched everywhere and all I tried so far are not working. What I want to do is to keep the parent URL or hide the URL of the requested page or just anything that will work I will appreciate.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically you're doing and why?

Comment: please can explain more or paste what you have done so far?